# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Python: How to configure the environment to use selenium?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a an AWS Elastic Beanstalk Python2.7 environment and my application uses selenium. It has the following line for example

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
```

When I ssh to the server and run the code from there (after installing all the required packages), the code runs fine, however when I open the service url to run the code through the webserver I get the following error

```
ImportError: No module named selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities
```

I have a configuration file named packages.config under .ebextensions with the following

```
packages:
  python:
    selenium: []
```

The server for sure parses the config file as it once failed to deploy when I had the wrong file format there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add your requirements.txt in the application root folder and deploy with your application.

Edit:

This turns to be the right answer, however to add to it, instead of creating requirements.txt yourself, if you have everything installed through pip, you can extract it using pip freeze >> requirements.txt